# problem with counting the stock of monetary values

Tags: c

Objective: to make a code that breaks down monetary values according to the stock.
Stock: 4 bills of 200; 2 notes of 100 and 3 notes of 50.
Error: When typing a thousand dollars, an error message is displayed that cannot be decomposed, as there are only 4 notes in the stock. But it would be possible to decompose 4 notes of two hundred dollars and 2 notes of one hundred dollars. The error is in the part of the error message that disregards when the first pass of the IF is already blocked, I think.

```
#include <stdio.h>

 int main()
{

    int value, ced200, ced100, ced50, ced20, ced10, ced5, ced2, ced1;
    int rced200, rced100, rced50, rced20, rced10, rced5, rced2, rced1;
 
    printf("n Enter a monetary value: ");
    scanf("%d" , & value );

    ced200 = value / 100;
    ced200 = value % 100;

    ced100 = rced200 / 100;
    rced100 = rced200 % 100;

    ced50 = rced100 / 50;
    rced50 = rced100 % 50;

    if ( ced200 > 4)
    {
        printf(" not enough notes", ced200);
    }
    else {
    printf("\n The quantity of notes of $ 200 and: %d", ced200);
        }

    if ( ced100 > 2)
    {
        printf(" not enough notes", ced100);
    }
    else {
    printf("\n The quantity of notes of $ 100 and: %d", ced100);
        }
    if ( ced50 > 3)
    {
        printf(" not enough notes", ced50);
    }
    else {
    printf("\n The amount of notes of $ 50 and: %d", ced50);
        }

    return 0;
}
``
```

Comment: Is this a typo? You are overwriting the value of ced200 in the first few lines.

Comment: And what is other?